# How to derive the Einstein-Skyrme equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, skyrmion

I would like to derive the [Einstein-Skyrme equations](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Einstein+Skyrme). The action can be read as

\begin{equation}
S[g,U] = \int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\biggl[R + \frac{K}{4}Tr\bigg(A^{\mu}A_{\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{8}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\bigg)\biggr]
\end{equation}
where the constants $K$ and $λ$ are the ones corresponding to the Skyrme coupling, and $A_{\mu}=U^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}U$ with $U\in SU(2)$ and strength of the field is $F_{\mu\nu}=[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]$. The equation that I do not know how to get is associated to the variation of $A_{\mu}$

\begin{equation}
\nabla^{\mu}A_{\mu} + \frac{\lambda}{4}\nabla^{\mu}[A^{\nu},F_{\mu\nu}]=0.
\end{equation}